# MySQL: Read from the right table or the default

Tags: mysql, internationalization

I'm using a table to save some *text* data with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `strings_en` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

This table keeps all english "strings" (really this is a text that sometimes is longer that 4kb). When I need a string I call mySQL like this:

```
SELECT `content` FROM `strings_en` WHERE `id`='42'
```

Now, I have "internationalized" my application so I have added other tables called "strings_es" or "strings_de" where spanish and dutch languages are used. Each id matches allways the same string in different languages.

In PHP I have a *$language* variable that contains the current selected language: 'es' for spanish, 'en' for english, etc. I get an string with this query:

```
SELECT `content` FROM `strings_$language` WHERE `id`='$string'
```

The problem is sometimes there is no translation for a given id (this id not exists in the table). For instance, in spanish doesn't exists id=10 (strings_es), but it exists in english (strings_en). I use *strings_en* as **default**, so when a string don't exist in the current language I search in english. Now I'm doing this through a PHP conditional:

```
$result = query("SELECT `content` FROM `strings_$language` WHERE `id`='$string'");
if (empty($result)) {
    $result = query("SELECT `content` FROM `strings_en` WHERE `id`='$string'");
}
```

I would like to know how to do this in only one MySQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the language inside your strings table and make it part of the unique key (id+language). This way you won't have to add new tables when you use more and more languages.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `strings` (
  `string_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  `language` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'en',
  `title` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`string_id`) ,
  `i_id_lang`  UNIQUE INDEX (id,language)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

And with

```
( SELECT * FROM strings WHERE id=? AND language=? UNION 
  SELECT * FROM strings WHERE id=? AND language='en' ) LIMIT 1
```

you would get a string for the id in a given language or the default language.

Edit: I added a `string_id` column to act as the unique id.

Comment: I know. The problem here is that 'id' is primary so is not possible to add new rows with the ID. And I cannot remove the PRIMARY KEY because there are other (external) modules that expect to receive an error if id is duplicated. Common problems with inherited code :(

Comment: @Ivan I added a `string_id` column to act as unique key for the strings table and now you could use the `id` column as desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COALESCE(other, en)
FROM (
    SELECT (SELECT `content` FROM `strings_$language` WHERE id = `$string`) as other,
    (SELECT `content` FROM `strings_en` WHERE id = `$string`) as en
) a
```

Comment: Returns: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a' at line 5

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ISNULL(l.`content`, e.`content`) AS `content`
FROM `strings_en` AS e
LEFT OUTER JOIN `strings_$language` AS l ON l.`id` = e.`id`
WHERE e.`id` = `$string`
```